# ElasticSearch.Net - Update array with multiple components

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I've got data indexed using ElasticSearch, and I'm having trouble updating a particular field. A snippet of the JSON is as follows:

```
 {
 "_index": "indexName",
 "_type": "type",
 "_id": "00001",
 "colors": [
     "red",
     "green"
 ]
 "place": "london",
 "person": [
      {
           "name": "john",
           "age": "27",
           "eyes": "blue"
      }
      {
           "name": "mary",
           "age": "19",
           "eyes": "green"
      }

 ]
 }
```

I need to add in a new `person` object, something like:

```
{
    "name": "jane",
    "age": "30",
    "eyes": "grey"
}
```

I've got `People` defined as follows:

```
public class People
{
    public List<string> colors {get; set; }
    public string place {get; set; }
    public List<Person> person {get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public string name {get; set; }
    public string age {get; set; }
    public string eyes {get; set; }
}
```

I updated `color` with no problems by doing:

```
client.Update<People>(u => u
    .Id(u.Id)
    .Index(u.Index)
    .Type(u.Type)
    .Script("if ctx._source.containsKey(\"color\")) { ctx._source.color += color; } else { ctx._source.color = [color] }")
    .Params(p => p
        .Add("color", "pink"))
);
```

I can't figure out how to update the `person` field though, as it's a list of `Person` objects rather than a list of strings.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this previously by using an anonymous object and sending a partial document update to Elasticsearch to only update the needed section.

Here is a code snippet that should work...

```
var peopleId = //Get Id of document to be updated.
var persons = new List<Person>(3);
persons.Add(new Person { name = "john", eyes = "blue", age = "27" });
persons.Add(new Person { name = "mary", eyes = "green", age = "19" });
persons.Add(new Person { name = "jane", eyes = "grey", age = "30" });

var response = Client.Update<People, object>(u => u
            .Id(peopleId)
            .Doc(new { person = persons})
            .Refresh()
        );
```

Comment: No good - nothing gets updated.
I've tried different variations of passing in a Person object to the update statement, none of which have worked.

Comment: Looks like the .Doc property should be set with the update. I have updated my example above accordingly.You might want to try using an anonymous object as shown in the NEST documentation - http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html under the Anonymous objects as partial documents section.

Comment: I've tried this too with no success, but thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: I was able to get this working using the anonymous object. I have updated my answer and included a full working example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/2v08C6